# TFS REST API: Item history

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015

I'm using the TFS Powershell cmdlets to get the history of source control folder: Get-TfsItemHistory -HistoryItem ...

Now I have to get the same behavior on a computer without these cmdlets (I can't install Visual Studio on it) so I was trying to use the REST API but I can't find the corresponding API.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the REST API of changesets under version control.  There is a option **By item path** which get the changesets that contain changes to the specified item.

Sample request

```
GET https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?searchCriteria.itemPath=$/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/AuthSample/AuthSample/Program.cs&api-version=1.0
```

More detailed info please refer the link from MSDN: [Changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets)

Comment: Can you confirm that it supports to get the changesets filtered by label range?

Comment: No, it's not support through REST API for now.